# How to split Recycler view into 2 divisions based on type from a JSON file in Kotlin - android studio

Tags: android, json, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview

So I'm trying to show all the data from a JSON file in a recyclerview, and that works fine.
My data has 2 types of accounts, bank account & card account. I'm trying to put them all in on recyclerview but split them into 2 categories each with a title above the category. All need to scroll up and down as one.

- group 1 all the card accounts together
- group 2 all the bank accounts together

Below is my adapter, works great but doesn't split things as needed. Any ideas?

```
    class DataAdapter(private val list: List<Data>, var context: Context) : 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.DataViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DataViewHolder {
       val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.bank_card_view,parent, 
    false)

        return  DataViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DataViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = list[position]

        holder.card.setOnClickListener(object :View.OnClickListener{
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {

                val intent = Intent(context, DetailsActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("name",currentItem.account_name)
                intent.putExtra("desc",currentItem.desc)
                intent.putExtra("type",currentItem.account_type)
                context.startActivity(intent)

            }
        })

        holder.name.text = (currentItem.account_name)
        holder.description.text = (currentItem.desc)

        if (currentItem.account_type.equals("card")){
            holder.img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.baseline_credit_card_black_48pt_1x)
            holder.type.text = context.getString(R.string.card)
        }
        else{

            holder.img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.baseline_account_balance_black_48pt_1x)
            holder.type.text = context.getString(R.string.bank)
        }



    }

    override fun getItemCount() = list.size

    class DataViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        val name: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.account_name)
        val description: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc)
        val type: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.type)
        val card: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card)
        val img: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img)

    }

}
```

This is my JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "account_type":"bank", 
        "account_name":"", 
        "desc": ""
    },
    {
        "account_type":"card", 
        "account_name":"", 
        "desc": ""

    }
]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up filtering through my json file and splitting it into 2 lists. One that contains all the card types, another for all the bank types. Then passing each through their individual recycler.

```
val cardData: MutableList <Data> = mutableListOf<Data>()
        val bankData: MutableList <Data> = mutableListOf<Data>()

        for(i in data) {
            if (i.account_type.equals("card")){
                cardData.add(i)
        }
    }

        for(i in data) {
            if (i.account_type.equals("bank")){
                bankData.add(i)
            }
        }
```

To clarify, data is a list that uses the helper class Data using Gson, assign the json file to it in my main activity.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great solution for your case here in this codelab, you should take a look: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-headers#3

You can override the `getItemViewType` function to inflate different types of view holders inside a single RecyclerView.

Then, you can use the kotlin function `map` or `filter` to reorganize your list and add a header type before populating the adapter, to inflate a header view holder to each section.